# Java program works on most but not all computers

Tags: java, class, startup, runtime-error, program-entry-point

Ok, I recently wrote a program for my fathers company. I tested it on both of my computers, my dad's computer, and my mom's computer before he sent it out. He sent the beta version to his CEO, and 4 others. It worked just fine for the CEO and 3 others. However, one person got an error when he tried to open the program that said "The main startup class could not be found."
I know that this means it could not find the main class or method, I just don't know why. He said he installed the latest version of java and I provided the right download link when I distributed the program. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Have you bundled your program as an executable JAR?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "executable JAR" because the Windows file system is not able to set the file association in that fashion.  I think what travega means is did you archive your .jar with this command:  "jar cfm MyJar.jar Manifest.txt MyPackage/*.class"   and by putting into the Manifest.txt the string: "Main-Class: MyPackage.MyClass"  .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of different factors that can cause this, but the most probable is that the computers don't have the appropriate `Java Version`.

My approach to solve this is to make the program in Java 5 standard. The very most part of the computers today should have at least JRE5.

As you are developing in NetBeans, try changing the compiling level of your project as described [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/charliebrown/entry/how_to_set_and_use)

Comment: Thank you very much for responding. So can I just compile it on a machine with JRE5 and that'll do it?

Comment: No, the JRE (Runtime Environment) is not the same as the JDK (Development Kit). Are you using eclipse? And like travega asked, have you exported it as runnable JAR?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say this in the question, but yes it is a jar but I use launch4j to wrap it because my dad wanted an exe. As for my IDE, I use netbeans.